# Extract links inside embed tags in WordPress

Tags: the-content, youtube

I am using the default WordPress embed to embed a couple of videos in the content.

I want to extract the video link from `[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY[/embed]`, can anyone help with the regex?

Comment: how you are getting your content ?? Using loop or using a wp function ??

Comment: @Harry I am using the loop. 

Inside the loop: `if ( has_post_format( 'video' ) ) {  $video_content = get_the_content(); }` and the ouput is `[embed]https://youtube.com/sfsdfsf[/embed]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use regex. WordPress has a handy function to [strip shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) from a string.

Use `strip_shortcodes( $content )`.

So in your case,

```
$content = "[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY[/embed]";

$your_clean _url = strip_shortcodes( $content );

echo $your_clean_url; // should output https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY
```

**EDIT**

Here's a function (tested) that will remove your *"unwanted"* shortcode, and any other one.

```
function remove_unwanted_shortcode($shortcode, $content) {
    $start = "[" . $shortcode . "]";
    $stop = "[/" . $shortcode . "]";

    $cleanFirst = str_ireplace($start, '', $content);
    $cleanSecond = str_ireplace($stop, '', $cleanFirst);

    return $cleanSecond;
}
```

And you would use it like so:

```
$content = "[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY[/embed]";
$short = "embed";
echo remove_unwanted_shortcode($shortcode, $content);
```

Comment: Than you so much @samuel-asor... That's clean and does the job very nicely. I owe you one.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: One more thing, please mark the answer as accepted... :)

Answer (score 0):

if only want to display your video link you can put the link like

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY</a>
```

(it will display your link like hyperlink )

Comment: This is not what I mean. I have `[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9QbYZh1YXY[/embed]` when I get `$content = get_the_content()`. I want to remove those tags and only get the URL